# What is the difference between ListView onItemClickListener vs having a custom Listener in Adapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, onitemclicklistener

I have a **ListView** with an **editText** item.
**My Listview can be clickable**. When clicked a detail screen will be opened.
Each ListView row has an editText. When EditText is clicked, the keyboard is oped up and a number can be input.

Since I cannot use onItemClickListener if I have focusable items in list row, I choose to use a custom listener. In the adapter:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        onCustomClickListener.onItemClick(position);
    });
}
```

The  onCustomClickListener is implemented in the Fragment. this solution worked as expected for me.

My question is what is the difference between onItemClickListener and this custom listener? Is the onItemClickListener somehow optimised and this is why we usually use it?

In a **ListView** we cannot have both the **row (focusable)** and items that can also be **focusable (editText)**. If we have an editText in the list row, than the **onItemClickListener will not be called** if we don t add:
`android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in the list row.xml layout.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot see your fragment code, I can only guess, that there is some kind of switch case, which chooses EditView by position, right? There is no optimization in using this kind of listener. As you said,

> Since I cannot use onItemClickListener if I have focusable items in list row

so your implementation of setting to each row view a listener that calls custom listener from fragment is only a hack to deal with the quoted problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the list row.xml I have a custom View which has the EditText I want to click on. In my case I want to be able to click on both the row and the editText. Having a custom listener when clicking on the row fixes the issue I got. You know that in a ListView we theoretically cannot have view with focus on them and row that has also a focus. My Question is what is the difference between setOnItemClickListener and a callback from the adapter in the fragment. The callback is called from the getView(..). Is there any difference?